# tkinter+urllib progressbar

Tags: python, tkinter, urllib

пытаюсь скачать файл и к нему сделать отображение прогресса скачивания. Но почему-то получаю значение `total_size = -1`

```
filename = 'update.tar.gz'
url = 'https://www.mediafire.com/file/7yr25hxugnn207t/0ups.tar.gz/file?dkey=kflcompdjag&r=447'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename, show_progress)

def show_progress(block_num, block_size, total_size):
    bar.config(maximum=total_size)

    downloaded = block_num * block_size

    if downloaded < total_size:
        bar['value'] = downloaded
        bar.place(x=10, y=50)
    else:
        print('finish')

bar = Progressbar(window, length=280)
bar['value'] = 0
```

Comment: Значит сервер не дает информацию о полном размере файла.

Comment: @insolor и как это можно исправить? или облако менять только?

Comment: Я проверил, ссылка которая у вас в url ведет не напрямую на файл, а на страницу скачивания, на которой уже выскакивает сообщение с предложением сохранить файл. Вот при скачивании файла если скопировать его фактическую ссылку (у меня это было `https://download942.mediafire.com/hwrsppvq4tqg/7yr25hxugnn207t/0ups.tar.gz`, но она может каждый раз заново генерироваться), то по ней в headers дается размер файла (content-length), и скорее всего с этой ссылкой размер файла будет корректно передаваться: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KExX.png

Comment: Остается разобраться, как эту ссылку программно получить

Comment: @insolor понял. вот с постоянной ссылкой у меня нет такого парамметра: url = 'https://www.mediafire.com/file/7yr25hxugnn207t/0ups.tar.gz'
    d = requests.head(url)
    print(dict(d.headers))

Comment: @insolor короче пока вижу выход парсить ссылку и получать нужную и все